# assignment to readonly property

Tags: viewcontroller, tabview

This has been working just fine fore about 4 hours and i didn't even touch it but now I'm getting an assignment to readonly property and _tabBarController? Did you mean UITabBarController? What i had did was take this from the appdelegate because i added a login screen, at the login screen i haven't coded it so i just made the submit button on the login screen run the tabview part of my application. So I don't know what i did like i said its been working for a long time like that. Anyone have any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[AlarmViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlarmViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController4 = [[[BusPassViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BusPassViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4];
[self presentViewController:_tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Can you ask it with some more clarity. structure of your question is messy ..

Comment: hmmm self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease]; was throwing a "assignment to readonly property" and [self presentViewController:_tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil]; asked me " _tabBarController? Did you mean UITabBarController?"

Comment: how exactly yout tabBarController property is declared ? can you add it in your question ?

Comment: Use [self presentViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil]; instead